# Как вывести количество процессов, название которых начинается на определенную букву? linux

Tags: linux, консоль, redhat

Как вывести количество процессов, название которых начинается на определенную букву?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
pgrep -c '^a'
```

Выводит количество процессов начинающихся на букву `a`.

**Объяснение**

- `pgrep -c '^a'`

  - `pgrep` - программа для поиска процессов соответствующих паттерну.
  - `-c` = `--count` - вывести количество совпадающих процессов.
  - `'^a'` - регулярное выражение.

Чтобы посмотреть названия этих процессов:

```
pgrep -l '^a'
```

`-l` = `--list-name` - выводит имя процесса дополнительно к ID процесса.